# What statistical test should I use? - Limited information

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Say I have a list of patients who have a disease A. I also know the prevalence of disease B in the general population, but I do NOT know the prevalence of disease A in the general population, and I don't have any other data on patients with disease B. I would like to perform a statistical test to find out whether disease A is associated with disease B. Is there a test I can perform with this limited information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how many of your patients have disease B and you know the over all prevalence of B in the population then you can use the binomial distribution. Suppose, to make matters concrete, you have seen 100 people with A of whom 30 have B and you know the overall prevalence of B is 0.1. The you need to calculate the probability of seeing 30 or more positives (B) when you sample 100 times from a binomial distribution with $p=0.1$. Your favourite statistical software should let you do this as it is very tedious by hand.